# Can't get redux in react-native to work

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, redux, jsx

I'm trying to run through a very minimal redux example:

http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/redux

It's the first box of code. All it does is store a number and with a reducer that just increments it. The code only imports redux (no redux-persist, react-redux, etc)

The problem I have is getting all of the dependencies down. I had no problems running react-native apps until redux. After a react-native init  and executing a run-ios a redbox error shows it can't find redux. This is the only part that makes sense to me. Here are the steps I tried taking:

```
$ npm install --save redux
```

This proved to be problematic as it does a rollback and does the following:

> added 5 packages, removed 617 packages and updated 17 packages in
>   8.839s

run-ios or run-android no longer works as it gives:

> Command `run-ios` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm
>   install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

Doing an npm install or npm install update does nothing as it still shows this message.

So then I tried creating a new project and pasting the code into index.ios.js again but using yarn instead (btw, I don't know what any of this means. npm or yarn.)

```
$ yarn add redux
```

Then run-ios shows an red box error:

> Can't find variable: React

The error is on

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 100}}>
```

so it must be something in react-native (ReactCompositeComponent.js to be exact). Okay.

```
$ yarn add react
```

Now the red box error I'm getting is that it can't resolve react/lib/ReactDebugCurrentFrame and then it lists all of the default directories that it can't find it in.

npm install --save redux shouldn't be deleting all of those node_module files. Can anyone else make this work?

Comment: It shouldn't delete node_module files as far as I'm aware? How did you create your react native project? Did you use the `react-native init`?

Comment: Yes I used react-native init. From what I'm aware of I should be able to just do npm install --save redux and it should just work. But it's deleting a lot of files.

Comment: The main problem is that your `npm install --save redux` is deleting a lot of files in node_modules. Did you follow the steps here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Yes, I even did it again and react-native and watchman were up to date. react-native-cli updated itself but I'm still having this issue. It's very bizzare. I'm on a mac.

Comment: Maybe related to this issue? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems. The first one was npm install --save redux (or even react-redux) was deleting a lot of node_modules. I never figured out why it was doing that, but after reinstalling node and watchman (brew uninstall --force then install) it stopped doing that. The second problem was that I needed to add import React, { Component } from 'react'; to the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add packages with yarn only if you have yarn installed globally.Command **react-native init project-name** uses yarn by default  . So trying to install packages with **npm install** will delete node_modules because initial setup of react native app was not with npm.